# Can bulk_update fail to update some records but succeed overall?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a situation where I export between 5 to 20k records to a csv file and then bulk update the exported rows to reflect they've been exported with a Boolean field once the file has been successfully created. I'm using:

```
MyData.objects.bulk_update(data, ['exported'])
```

We've ran this process a few times for a total of ~60k records exported but we're seeing that ~0.17% of the `MyData`s were not updated across all runs. So, some of the records included in the bulk update were updated while others were not; no exceptions thrown.

How can this be?

Comment: It can happen by a multitude of reasons, including DB specifics (are you using non-relational DB?), transaction isolation, replications etc. Django has nothing to do with it; it only translates ORM into the underlying SQL/whatever, so this is more of a general database question.

Comment: @Marat, it's postgres. The ORM translation bit makes sense but I would expect a bulk update to be wrapped in a transaction but I'm new to django's ORM.

Comment: I would try to log DB queries (django-debug-toolbar can help), find the one that causes problems and run it manually.